# How to create a parse query with 'OR' behaviour in android?

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

Parse queries for multiple fields can easily be made as follows:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("MyParseClass");
query.whereGreaterThan("price",15)
    .whereExists("validity")
    .findInBackGround();
```

This however behaves as an AND logic: "Retrieve all MyParseClass objects where the price is greater than 15 AND the validity exists".

But I want to create a query based on OR logic: "Retrieve all MyParseClass objects where the price is greater than 15 OR the validity exists"

Can this be done using the Android API of parse?
If so, what would the equivalent code look like?

**Other relevant information:**

- Using parse for android API: 1.8.1 (from Facebook SDK)
- minSDK 9

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-compound    "parse.query.or" is in the docs

Comment: Gosh this is embarrassing! I can't believe I didn't see that!